# How to: Schedule snapshot of OpenStack instance

Tags: image, backup, openstack, snapshot

I need to schedule snapshot of OpenStack instance. I'm wondering if this can be done through the UI. Or is it terminal only?

Answer (score 1):

By "through the UI", I presume you mean ... using the OpenStack Dashboard.

Backup in OpenStack is a bit complicated.  Services like Nova, Cinder and Trove each have their of mechanisms for backup the resources that they manage.

In addition, there is a service called Freezer that is designed to orchestrate backups ... in various ways.  For example, it can perform a Nova instance snapshot, a Cinder volume backup or a Glance image backup.  Furthermore, Freezer has a mechanism for scheduling periodic backups.  See the
[Freezer: Agent User Guide](https://docs.openstack.org/freezer/latest/user/freezer-agent.html).

So to answer your question:

- Nova doesn't support backup scheduling.
- The base Horizon Dashboard doesn't support scheduling either.
- If you set up Freezer, you should be able to use it to create a backup job to do a periodic instance snapshot.
- You can do other sorts of backup as will ... which might be more appropriate than instance snapshots.
- There is a Horizon plugin for Freezer.

But if it was up to me, AND all I wanted to do was regular instance snapshots for a fixed set of instances, I would just use `cron` to do the scheduling and either shell or Python scripts to orchestrate the instance snapshots.